# rails 4, change default form builder globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have sub-classed the default form builder to add some additional methods.  Sample code is below.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    class AppFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
        def coordinates_field(method, options = {})
            options[:readonly] = 'true'
            ....
            @template.text_field(@object_name, method, objectify_options(options))
        end
    end
end
```

This works well, but to use it I have to change the view code for every form that uses the `coordinates_field` method, i.e.,

```
<%= form_for @object, :builder => ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

It sounds like it is theoretically possible to change the default form builder globally (`config.action_view.default_form_builder`), but I can't seem to get this to work.  This is what I have tried in `/config/application.rb`:

```
module Web
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.action_view.default_form_builder = "ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder"
  end
end
```

Which results in error *undefined method 'new' for "ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder":String* when I hit a view that has a form.

If I instead try this

```
config.action_view.default_form_builder = ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder
```

I get the error *config.action_view.default_form_builder = ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder* when the application starts.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApplicationHelper::AppFormBuilder` is not required yet at the time application.rb loads. You can try to put this in a separate initializer file (create one in config\initializers):

```
module Web
  class Application
    ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = AppFormBuilder
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the [official docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/FormBuilder.html), in **Rails 5** the correct way is to specify it in a controller. To make it application wide, just set in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  default_form_builder AppFormBuilder
end
```

This makes much more sense. FormHelpers are part of the view layer and not the application config.

Answer (score 3):

I like Max's answer, but (rails n00b here so YMMV) I believe this is equivalent and cleaner, directly in config/application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = MyCustomHelper::MyCustomFormBuilder
end
```

obviously you replace the names MyCustomHelper and MyCustomFormBuilder.

took me about 48hrs to figure this out, thanks to all that well-structured rails documentation.

Comment: @d4n3 That's true, but so does Max's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set this from an initializer as you would for other config options. Create a `default_form_builder.rb` file under `config/initializers/`. The syntax should simpler than in @Max's answer.

```
Rails.application.config.action_view.default_form_builder = AppFormBuilder
```

I suggest you do not include this in a helper. Add it as separate class inside the `/lib` directory. You may or may not need to prefix the with the module it's contained within.

Finally, [you can set this globally](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-view) from `config/application.rb`, but you would have to pass it as a string since the class may not be loaded when rails starts up.

```
config.action_view.default_form_builder = 'AppFormBuilder'
```

Comment: Why put it in `/lib` instead of `/app/helper`?

Comment: The initializer with simpler syntax generated an error with `rails server`: `bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here`.

Comment: The above error is another way of saying my AppFormBuilder cannot be found.  `rails console` generated a better error message.

Comment: @JustinC because it's reusable, and not specific to your app. In theory it should be 'plug-in-play', or, in this case, drag-and-drop, if you will. I drop in form builders in my apps all the time.

Comment: Mohamad, thanks for elaborating.  I was confused after reading a few issues on the rails github that mentioned problems with using `/lib` in production.  Pixeltrix recommended `/app/lib` instead, since `/lib` may contain development-only files (I lack the experience to understand this concern).  e.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13602  Cheers.

Comment: @JustinC np. I don't really feel the need to do that. I don't usually keep development dependencies in lib. I create a support folder for testing, and am yet to come across something that needs to go in lib and is only used in dev. It's a bit of a moot point, having the lib folder under app does take away the need of having to add the lib dir into the load path.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5+

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  default_form_builder AppFormBuilder
end
```

Rails 4

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = AppFormBuilder
end
```

... or if you prefer an initializer, I'd recommend setting it as a string instead, that way you will not have to restart Rails every time you change something in your form builder..  (since the class may not be loaded when rails starts up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992240/2037928)

```
module Web
  class Application
    ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = "AppFormBuilder"
  end
end
```

Comment: We did use `default_form_builder` in our ApplicationController first but that did not work well with our rspec suite. Your last example here was a great solution for us.