# Rails printing literal label object instead of label tag in form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Rails project that's been running without any issues for the last year. I cloned it today and launched the instance locally (inside a VM) and all labels now display like this:

```
<label object="#<Organization:0x000055ae1b1ea888>">organization</label>
```

Instead of the `<label />` tag. Nothing significant has changed other than a new controller and views.

[image]

The code generating it:

```
<div class="uk-margin">
    <%= f.label :name, class: "uk-form-label" %>
  <div class="uk-form-controls">
        <%= f.text_field :name, maxlength: 100, required: true, class: 'uk-input', placeholder: 'ACME Incorporated Inc' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought it might be something broken in the local instance, so I pushed to production and now the same thing is happening there.

Does anyone know how to go about fixing this?

EDIT:

Here's the full form:

```
<%= form_for @organization, url: url do |f| %>
  <div class="uk-margin">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <%= f.text_field :name, maxlength: 100, required: true, class: 'uk-input', placeholder: 'ACME Incorporated Inc' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="uk-margin">
    <%= f.label :tax_number %>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <%= f.text_field :tax_number, maxlength: 100, required: false, class: 'uk-input', placeholder: '0000000000' %>
    </div>
  </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**:

This occurs in all forms.

The output from `f.method(:label).source_location` is:

```
/home/vagrant/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb", 2025
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Switching to form_with, results in the labels being printed like this instead:

```
<label skip_default_ids="false" allow_method_names_outside_object="true" object="#<Merchant:0x00007ff24c079810>">Category</label>
```

Comment: can you post the full form ?

Comment: @DavidGeismar Updated with the full form. Problem is that it's all forms doing this throughout the app, not just this one.

Comment: check what you have in ```@organization.name```

Comment: @DavidGeismar `@organization` is the model instance and `name` is a string that returns "Test Org"

Comment: Do you have any monkeypatches applied to `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`? Or do you have a [custom form builder set up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821204/544825)? Do you have any gems that could be responsible?

Comment: @max No monkeypatching going on at the moment, I'm busy auditing the gems at the moment.

Comment: You can try `f.method(:label).source_location` and see if it has been redefined.

Comment: @max It returns: `/home/vagrant/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb", 2025`

Comment: That's looks right. This issue is pretty strange. Do you get the same results when you use the lower level `label_tag` helper? For example `label_tag 'foo', 'bar'`?

Answer (score 0):

according to the current actionview documentation, the output that you get is the expected one (check this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label) ). There is a chance that this behavior changed from one version to another. Check if you updated any gem during the last deployment that could influence such a change.